# ElasticNetCV in Python vs cvglmnet in R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, regression, glmnet

Has anybody tried to rich same results by implementing ElasticNetCV in Python and cvglmnet in R?
I have found out how to make it on ElasticNet in Python and glmnet in R but cannot reproduce it with cross validation methods...

**Steps to reproduce in Python:**

*Preprocessing:*

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet, ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

data = make_regression(
    n_samples=100000,
    random_state=0
)
X, y = data[0], data[1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.25)

pd.DataFrame(X_train).to_csv('X_train.csv', index=None)
pd.DataFrame(X_test).to_csv('X_test.csv', index=None)
pd.DataFrame(y_train).to_csv('y_train.csv', index=None)
pd.DataFrame(y_test).to_csv('y_test.csv', index=None)
```

*Models:*

```
model = ElasticNet(
    alpha=1.0,
    l1_ratio=0.5,
    fit_intercept=True,
    normalize=True,
    precompute=False,
    max_iter=100000,
    copy_X=True,
    tol=0.0000001,
    warm_start=False,
    positive=False,
    random_state=0,
    selection='cyclic'
)

model.fit(
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train
)

y_pred = model.predict(
    X=X_test
)

print(
    mean_squared_error(
        y_true=y_test,
        y_pred=y_pred
    )
)
```

output: 42399.49815189786

```
model = ElasticNetCV(
    l1_ratio=0.5,
    eps=0.001,
    n_alphas=100,
    alphas=None,
    fit_intercept=True,
    normalize=True,
    precompute=False,
    max_iter=100000,
    tol=0.0000001,
    cv=10,
    copy_X=True,
    verbose=0,
    n_jobs=-1,
    positive=False,
    random_state=0,
    selection='cyclic'
)

model.fit(
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train
)

y_pred = model.predict(
    X=X_test
)

print(
    mean_squared_error(
        y_true=y_test,
        y_pred=y_pred
    )
)
```

output: 39354.729173913176

**Steps to reproduce in R:**

*Preprocssing:*

```
library(glmnet)
X_train <- read.csv(path)
X_test <- read.csv(path)
y_train <- read.csv(path)
y_test <- read.csv(path)
fit <- glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train))
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))
y_error = y_test - y_pred
mean(as.matrix(y_error)^2)
```

output: 42399.5

```
fit <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train))
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))
y_error <- y_test - y_pred
mean(as.matrix(y_error)^2)
```

output: 37.00207

Comment: something must be wrong.. how did you calculate the mse with cvglmnet? mse is in the range of the variance of your response variable. what would be that value and you cannot get somethign so different

Comment: Just using mean((fact_values - predicted_values)^2). It's working when I use glmnet. I've compared predicted values of cvglmnet and ElasticNetCV and there is huge difference... I can give you some steps to reproduce.

Comment: hey @Joger, as I mentioned, rough ball estimate, the mse should be around variance of y. what is the variance of y? It should be close to what you get from glmnet. This means you are either fitting something weird in python or you calculated it wrongly in python

Comment: @StupidWolf okay, I'll check it's strange conclusion cause ElasticNet and glmnet are giving me same results and mse with my functions. How can it be wrong on cv models and right at single models?

Comment: @StupidWolf I've added all steps for reproducing.

Comment: thanks for providing the code, I have gone through them and hopefully the answer below makes sense.. It is confusing between R and python, how the options mean different things. Always check the formula again.. I have to check it every time i use either one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks so much for providing the example, I am on a laptop so I had to reduce the number of samples to 100:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet, ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

data = make_regression(
    n_samples=100,
    random_state=0
)
X, y = data[0], data[1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.25)
```

When you do predict in with glmnet, you need to specify lambda, otherwise it returns the predictions for all lambdas, so in R:

```
fit <- glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train))
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))
dim(y_pred)
[1] 25 89
```

When you run cv.glmnet, it selects the best lambda from cv, the lambda.1se, so it gives you only 1 set, which is the rmse you wanted:

```
fit <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train))
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))
y_error <- y_test - y_pred
mean(as.matrix(y_error)^2)
[1] 22.03504

dim(y_error)
[1] 25  1
fit$lambda.1se
[1] 1.278699
```

If we select the lambda closest to that chosen by cv.glmnet in glmnet, you get back something in the correct range:

```
fit <- glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train))
sel = which.min(fit$lambda-1.278699)
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))[,sel]
mean((y_test - y_pred)^2)
dim(y_error)

mean(as.matrix((y_test - y_pred)^2))
[1] 20.0775
```

Before we compare with sklearn, we need to make sure we are testing over the same range of lambdas.

```
L = c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2)
fit <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(X_train), y=as.matrix(y_train),lambda=L)
y_pred <- predict(fit, newx = as.matrix(X_test))
y_error <- y_test - y_pred
mean(as.matrix(y_error)^2)
[1] 0.003065869
```

So we expect something in the range of 0.003065869. We run it with the same lambda, lambda is termed as alpha in ElasticNet. The alpha in glmnet is in fact your l1_ratio, see [vignette](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html). And the normalize option should be set to False, because:

> If True, the regressors X will be normalized before regression by
>   subtracting the mean and dividing by the l2-norm. If you wish to
>   standardize, please use sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler before
>   calling fit on an estimator with normalize=False.

So we just run it using CV:

```
model = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio=1,fit_intercept=True,alphas=[0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2])
model.fit(X=X_train,y=y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X=X_test)
mean_squared_error(y_true=y_test,y_pred=y_pred)

0.0018007824874741929
```

It's around the same ball park as the R result.

And if you do it for ElasticNet, you will get the same result, if you specify alpha.

Comment: thanks for very deep explanation! Finaly I get exactly same results - you saved my day)